# I have downloaded deadlus wallet from the testnet and now what?

Tags: wallet, cardano-cli, token

I have downloaded deadalus wallet for testing with Ada from this link: https://testnets.cardano.org/en/testnets/cardano/get-started/wallet/

I couldn't find a link which helps me to figure out how to install the same on my linux 64 bit machine.

However, I have some questions:

1. How to install this in my local linux machine?
2. Do i have to take it online 24*7
3. Can i use the same wallet if i am going to use the real ada on this particular system.

My intention is to develop a token on the top of cardano block chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See IOHK Zendesk article: [Installing Daedalus Testnet wallet](https://iohk.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360013271313-Installing-Daedalus-Testnet-wallet)

> 1. Log in to the target Linux or UNIX system.
> 2. Go to the directory that contains the installation program.
> 3. Launch the installation by entering the following commands:
>
> ```
> chmod a+x filename.bin 
> ./filename.bin
> ```